# I got a problem in the to fit LogisticRegression in the titanic file

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, training-data, train-test-split

I have imported the titanic.csv file and clean the file , when i wanna fit it to the Logistic Regression it cause the error and it wisent solving

#### Can Anyone help to solve this problem??

```
*Survived   Age SibSp   Parch   Fare    male    Q   S   2   3
0   0   22.0    1   0   7.2500  1   0   1   0   1
1   1   38.0    1   0   71.2833 0   0   0   0   0
2   1   26.0    0   0   7.9250  0   0   1   0   1
3   1   35.0    1   0   53.1000 0   0   1   0   0
4   0   35.0    0   0   8.0500  1   0   1   0   1*
```

i cleaned the data like this and perform this code in it

```
X= titanic_data.drop("Survived", axis = 1)
y= titanic_data["Survived"]
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=1)
```

`from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression`

```
logmodels = LogisticRegression(random_state=1)
logmodels.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

#### while compiling the last line i got the error like this

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-05d5668a869d> in <cell line: 2>()
      
```
1 logmodels = LogisticRegression(random_state=1)
----> 2 logmodels.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _get_feature_names(X)
   1901     # mixed type of string and non-string is not supported
   1902     if len(types) > 1 and "str" in types:
-> 1903         raise TypeError(
   1904             "Feature names are only supported if all input features have string names, "
   1905             f"but your input has {types} as feature name / column name types. "

TypeError: Feature names are only supported if all input features have string names, but your input has ['int', 'str'] as feature name / column name types. If you want feature names to be stored and validated, you must convert them all to strings, by using X.columns = X.columns.astype(str) for example. Otherwise you can remove feature / column names from your input data, or convert them all to a non-string data type.
````

Comment: I ran your code and works okay to me. Perharps you should consider converting the `Survival` column into int.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear, and even suggests some code to run to fix the problem.